# Firebase - Best way to reorder entries in realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am trying to build a Queue management app. And I use Firebase `push()` to add new entries into Firebase real-time database. And the order of insertion is my default set.

For a particular scenario - I want to push some elements down by 2 or 3 steps .
Whats the best way to do it ? 
**Do I need to use firebase functions? 
Or Will I need a separate server to handle this logic ?**

Example : 
Say , I have  a set of 10 push requests from different client apps who want to get into the queue .
When the client doesn't arrive , i want to push them 5-7 places down in the queue.

**Is there a good approach to handle these scenarios without a server**

I was trying to put the logic on the client side but I guess it wouldn't help much if the client goes offline when using the phone.

Also, I don't have a queue number set as a child element , since the insertion order is being taken care by firebase . A queue# I guess would create conflicting entries if 2 + clients are trying to enter the queue simultaneously .Not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: If you need to order your database items, put a field in the item that helps you build a query that retrieves the items in the order you want.  What you see in the console is just ordered by the key of the child.

Comment: I want to actually change the order  at certain scenarios . I can do it easily with a server but is there a way where i push the user down and bring others up in the list etc.. just with firebase

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the order of the nodes in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). All the nodes are by default ordered by key. If you need to order your database elements by a specific criteria, just add another property in your item object that will help you build a query that retrieves the items in the order you want. Let's say you want to order your items by timestamp and you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
        |
        --- uid
             |
             --- name: "John"
             |
             --- age: 22
             |
             --- creationDate: 1534424049
```

To order your users by the date of creation, you should use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("creationDate");
```

Comment: Thanks . Actually I have the default list ordered by key since that is based on timestamp anyways. The default list needs to be reordered at particular scenarios, say the customer wants to come up a bit late and push himself down in the queue . For this I have a child called QueueNum . How can I reorder the queue based on certain conditions say the Queue num itself  . If I try to reorder at the client app end, i might end up with inconsistent values .

Comment: You're welcome. Let's stick to one question at a time. Do you think that my answer helped you for the initial issue? Because this sounds as another question which I cannot answer in a comment and using the only the data you provided in the question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Upvoted . But still it doesn't answer my original question completely